# No audio driver for ECS 7050-M v1.0a for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers

I have an Elitegroup 7050-M v1.0a motherboard and I've used the Realtek HD audio driver it came with for years under Windows XP. There was a nice mixer panel, an equalizer and sound profiles that added effects. All of these menus are gone now that I've moved on to Windows 7 64 Bit. All I have is the basic settings under system control -> sound, but they are not nearly as detailed.

To clarify: Sound works, but the advanced settings I got when using older OS's are gone.

Older drivers don't seem to work under Win7 and I can't find one for Win7. So how can I fully utilize the capabilities of my HD sound chip under Win7?

Comment: When you say "older drivers" have you tried Vista 64-bit drivers?

Comment: I've tried a few: 1. For a similar chip for Win7, 2. For the same chip for Vista64 3. Starting the control panel right from the XP installation (got dual boot)

Answer (score 1):

The odds are you're never going to get those 'extras' like effects and such working under Windows Vista or newer due to the change-over MS made to the sound sub-system.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Audio_Architecture):

> "Universal Audio Architecture (UAA) is an initiative unveiled in 2002 by Microsoft to standardize the hardware and class driver architecture for audio devices in modern Microsoft Windows operating systems. ... **Starting with Windows Vista, Microsoft requires all computer and audio device manufacturers to support Universal Audio Architecture** in order to pass Windows Logo."
>
> "The goal of the Universal Audio Architecture is to solve a very common problem in modern Microsoft Windows products, that of inconsistent support for audio. Due to the lack of a common system by which audio devices could describe their capabilities to the operating system, not to mention a lack of ability to control those capabilities, audio device manufacturers (such as Creative Labs, Realtek, Turtle Beach and others) have **had to provide a series of control panels and custom interfaces to let a user control the device**. This, in turn, requires kernel-mode drivers so that the user's actions can be communicated to the hardware itself. Poorly-written audio drivers have been a common source of system instability in Windows, especially with games that make use of extended audio card capabilities. These concerns prompted Microsoft to disable the audio stack entirely by default in Windows Server 2003."

You're actually lucky RealTek (and your MB manufacturer) were nice enough to provide ANY newer driver.  A *LOT* of people with older sound cards got to go buy new ones because the manufacturers didn't want to write even basic Vista+ UAA drivers for anything that wasn't their latest and greatest product.

Hope that helps...

Comment: Oh, that's interesting to know, and explains the problems I had with old sound cards, but I don't think this applies to my case. The mobo isn't even 3 years old. It's a HD / AC'97 chip which should be compliant with those newer standards.

Answer (score 0):

You can see if you a Vista driver will work with your Windows 7 set up.

Comment: Yeah I was hoping that too, but after about 90% progress there's an Error Code: 0xE0000235 telling me that the installation has failed.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I got the obvious idea from another site where I posted this, but I thought I let you guys know. Turns out I was approaching this from the wrong side.

ECS does in fact not supply drivers for their onBoard sound for Win7, and neither does Realtek, but Realtek has generic drivers (well I think its more of a GUI since the sound worked before already) that are working just fine.

That's why I couldn't find anything for my specific chipset.

Thanks for your help anyways.